# What is the objective function of LASSO in sklearn when we have multiple targets?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In sklearn's [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html), it says

> The optimization objective for Lasso is:
>
>  `(1 / (2 * n_samples)) * ||y - Xw||^2_2 + alpha * ||w||_1`

I'm wondering if the shape of `y` is `(n_targets, n_features)`, what is the definition of `||w||_1`, where the shape of `w` in this case would be `(n_features, n_targets)`.

Comment: Moreover, I'm wondering whether you don't mean `y` having shape `(n_samples, n_targets)` and `w` having shape `(n_targets, n_features)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you might see from [code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/linear_model/_coordinate_descent.py#L333) or [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html#sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.path), in such a case the norm of `w` becomes its [L_{2,1} norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm). The euclidean norm of `y - Xw` becomes the Frobenius norm of the corresponding matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If it becomes L_{2,1} norm, what's the difference of it from the ridge regression?

Comment: The generalization of the Euclidean norm to matrices leads to [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm). Thus, you'll have: `ridge` -->  `(1 / (2 * n_samples)) * ||Y - XW||^Fro_2 + 0.5 * alpha * ||W||_Fro^2`; `lasso` --> `(1 / (2 * n_samples)) * ||Y - XW||^Fro_2 + alpha * ||W||_21`.